# Google Play account deletion requirement - using firebase on android,ios

Tags: android, firebase, google-play

Is there sample source code available or guideline published by Firebase on same?  Looking for sample code in java which follows best practices specific to firebase in android mobile app

Google Play’s app account deletion requirements - https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/13327111

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#delete_a_user?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen - this takes care of all analytics, big query data captured as well?

Comment: The API I linked deletes the user account from Firebase Authentication. If you want to delete data from other products too, you will have to run code against the API of those services too. --- For some of those, this extension may be useful: https://firebase.google.com/docs/extensions/official/delete-user-data

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen - Thank you for the detail reply. I'll check it out. Is there plan for firebase to release a single workflow which will take care of all cleanups? that will be really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to delete the user account from Firebase Authentication, you can call [this API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#delete_a_user).

If you want to delete auxiliary data from specific other products, you can use this extension: [Delete User Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/extensions/official/delete-user-data).

If you need to delete data from other sources too, you will have to write your own application code for that. You can of course file a feature request for Firebase or the extension to add such functionality, but given the multitude of systems where such data could be stored, it is unlikely that will happen - and even less likely it'd happen in a timeframe that matches your needs.